# Installing Xgboost in python 2.7, windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, xgboost

i am having trouble installing xgboost to windows 7, python 2.7. 
i tried running

```
git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
cd xgboost; make; cd wrapper; python.py setup install --user
```

tyhe first line works just fine but the second does not. it says that it could not find the specified path, which is true because cd wrapper is not in make folder. Can anyone tell me what i am missing here? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line add the `--recursive` option.

> The newest version of xgboost uses submodule to maintain packages. So when you clone the repo, remember to use the recursive option.

So it will become `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`.

Follow this [Tutorial](https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/) for installing the XGBoost in Windows. But while checking out the XGBoost Repository. Do an additional step of `git checkout 9a48a40` and then follow all the steps of that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you have below three software on your windows machine, xgboost installation would be a cake walk.

```
A Python installation such as Anaconda
Git
MINGW
```

use below link for step-by-step approach.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en

it took me not more than 10 min to configure xgboost on windows machine with python.

Answer (score 1):

With the same config *(Anaconda Python 2.7 - Win 7 - Git - Mingw64*) the cake walk turned into nightmare.

I finally succeeded by using the precompiled files from  [Guido Tapias](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/)